# ¿Por que no se ve el menú de configuración de usuarios en SQL Server Management?

Tags: sql-server, login, configuración, security

Estoy intentando crear un nuevo usuario con permisos de solo lectura para mi base de datos pero al ir a la sección de seguridad y dar le clic a la opción de nuevo usuario únicamente me muestra en forma de texto el código para agregar el usuario pero no aparece la ventana de configuración de usuario y permisos.

¿Cómo puedo tener accesos a esta ventana de configuración?

Mi versión de SQL Server es 12.0.2000.8 y la de mi SQL Management  es 18.6

Comment: Si agregas una imagen, seria de ayuda, saludos

Comment: ¿Como muestro algo que no se ve? jeje

Comment: Ok, plop!, te sugiero revisar [ask] es importante agregar detalles a tus preguntas, de esta forma obtendrás buenas respuestas.

Comment: Creo que mi pregunta es clara y la problemática esta bien redactada ;)

Comment: Tienes 4 preguntas realizadas de las cuales ninguna obtuvo una respuesta, te sugiero  considerar mi consejo.

Comment: Únicamente eh echo 2 preguntas amigo, pero gracias por el consejo.

Comment: ¿Con qué tipo de usuario te estás conectando al motor de base de datos?

Comment: Con el administrador